# Default Content Type + Deserialization errors

Tags: servicestack

I have configured my AppHost with JSON as the default content type. Unfortunately in situations when ServiceStack fails to deserialize the request into the corresponding DTO it responds with an application/xml content. Here's an example response (I've omitted most of the message and stacktrace element values for brevity):

```
<UpsertResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
    <ResponseStatus>
        <ErrorCode>SerializationException</ErrorCode>
        <Message>Could not deserialize 'application/xml' request using ...</Message>
        <StackTrace>at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.CreateContentTypeRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, Type requestType, String contentType)...</StackTrace>
    </ResponseStatus>
</UpsertResponse>
```

I guess the response is encoded that way because the request was sending 'application/xml' content. Is there a way to force (or hook into) ServiceStack to use the default content type?

A bit more conext - not only does my service uses JSON as the default content type, but it (tries to) ensures that JSON is the only accepted content type via a global request filter, which checks Accept/Content-type headers during each read/write and short-circuits the request with a 400 response when the content type is not 'application/json'.

Comment: Anyone found a answer to this yet? Have you found a solution to this at all?